# Reverse Paging Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, paging

I have a scenario where I have to get paginated records in a reversed way using LINQ. Lets Assume I have 15 items in the order they were posted:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5.......... 15
```

Having a pages size of 5, if the user sends 1 as the `currentPage` in my method. Then I should be able to return `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` as the result set, if he sends 2 as the `currentPage` then I should return `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` and so on. How do I set the value that I give to the Skip method so that it would give me records in this way? And yes, I'm ordering the items in an ascending order by their dates too.

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple example of the logic:

```
var nums = new[] {1, 2, 3, ..., 15};

var lastFew = nums.Reverse().Take(5).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Or alternatively, as a list:

```
var nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, ..., 15};
nums.Reverse();
nums.RemoveRange(5); // removes from index 5 till end
nums.Reverse();
```

The actual implementation can vary depending on how your code is designed, etc, but that should get you started.

The key methods to use here are: `Reverse`, `Take` to limit the returned amount, and `Skip` to choose the starting index. If you use `Skip`, you can most likely avoid using `Reverse` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this (using EF):

```
var resultByDesc = db.Entities
                   .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateTime)
                   .Skip(page * itemsPerPage)
                   .Take(itemsPerPage)
                   .ToList();  // important! eager loading!
// it will be executed in your client side, not SQL.
var actualResult = resultByDesc.Reverse();
```